# Allure report with restassured not showing request response in report

Tags: maven, rest-assured, allure

I am expirementing with allure reports with restassured and testng where I have used the below dependency for generatign allure report with the request and response in the allure generated report.

Here are the dependency used.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-rest-assured -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here is the request where I am adding the allure suggested method.

```
Response res = given()
                .baseUri(api_base_url_client)
                .headers(headers)
                .body(payload)
                .filter(RestAssuredFilter.getRequestLoggingFilter())
                .filter(RestAssuredFilter.getResponseLoggingFilter())
                .filter(new AllureRestAssured())
                .when()
                .post(ApiPath.LOOKUP_POST.get_Api_Path(), sid);
```

But while executing mvn command, I am able to create the allure report but it doesnot show the request response in that report at the same time while executing its fails the build test with the below error

```
> io.qameta.allure.attachment.AttachmentRenderException: Could't render
> http attachment file
>         at myRequest(myRequestSanityTestCases.java:65)
> Caused by: freemarker.core.ParseException:  Syntax error in template
> "http-request.ftl" in line 1, column 7: Unknown FTL header parameter:
> output_format
```

Comment: Did you try this https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-java/issues/146?

Comment: @lucasnguyen17 I didnt get the part. More over, while going through the suggestion, dont know which part of freemaker and jbehave should be used, as I saw multiple freemaker types and jbehave.

Comment: I think it suggests add newest version freemarker to pom.xml. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.freemarker/freemarker/2.3.31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the allure documentation, `.filter(new AllureRestAssured())` should be part of Request specification.

In my case I was doing it in the Response which is not allured.

```
RequestSpecification request = given()
                                        .filter(new AllureRestAssured())
                                        .filter(new RequestLoggingFilter(requestCapture));
```